# Is zstd for zram actually available in Linux 4.15?

Tags: linux, kernel, zram, zstd

I found `zstd` in [`/drivers/block/zram/zcomp.c`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/block/zram/zcomp.c?h=v4.15#n32), but I can't find anything zstd-related in [`/crypto`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/crypto?h=v4.15).
So is zstd for zram actually available in Linux 4.15 or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s supposed to be available in 4.15, as long as the `CONFIG_CRYPTO_ZSTD` setting is enabled. The implementation lives in [`lib/zstd`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/lib/zstd).

However the `zram` integration expects to find `zstd` *via* the crypto API, as you discovered, and that part’s [missing](https://lkml.org/lkml/2017/9/8/824) — which explains why there’s no way to actually enable `CRYPTO_ZSTD`, and why there’s no code registering `zstd` with the crypto framework.